# css: how to surround an image with two other images vertically centered around the first one?

Tags: css

I am basically just trying to have the main picture surrounded by the two smaller arrows. What am I missing here?

```css
.buttonsImage {
  background-image: url('http://celineburnand.com//img/menu/navigation_menu.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 217px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 24px;
  vertical-align: text-center;
}

div#beforeBtn {
  background-position: -17px -41px;
  width: 21px;
}
div#afterBtn {
  background-position: -50px -40px;
  width: 21px;
}
```

```html
<article style="overflow-y: scroll;" class="image-detail">
    <div id="beforeBtn" class="buttonsImage"></div>
    <img id="main-drawing" src="http://celineburnand.com/img/drawings/6.jpg" width="640" height="200" alt="" style="display: inline;">
    <div id="afterBtn" class="buttonsImage"></div>
    <p><span style="font-style:italic">Circuit</span>, charcoal on paper, 200 x 150 cm, 2014</p> 
</article>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ubwr370L/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current markup, make both arrow `div`s `display: inline;` and remove `float: left;`. Then apply `vertical-align: middle;` to both `div`s and the `img`.

https://jsfiddle.net/ubwr370L/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
.image-detail {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

to avoid the arrows being moved if the width is insufficient.